# How do I get this AJAX request to work in my Ruby on Rails Table Reservation App?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Okay guys, lengthy question, but going to try and keep this as condensed as possible.

I have a table reservation app I'm trying to create, looks like this:

[image: Table Reservation App]

**When you click on any of the booths or the tables in the map, the "Table ID" field fills up with the number of the table you just selected (i.e table number "A1", etc). Afterwards, once you hit "Create a Reservation" the table then turns yellow to signify that the User who is currently signed in is now reserving the table.**

The app works fine, I was able to get the table to highlight in yellow (to show a successful reservation) and to get the User's email to become associated with the table upon making a reservation. There's a problem though.

**There are two types accounts, "Users" (the customer), and "Owners" (the actual owner of the restaurant you are currently trying to make a reservation for). On the Users side, they can see the table reserved, but I want the OWNER to also see that the User made the reservation as well (I want it to update dynamically, the moment the User creates the reservation and the table highlights in yellow to show that the reservation is good to go, so will the Owner).**

I was told AJAX was the way to go for this, but I have never used AJAX before in  my life, and the tutorials I am looking at also aren't quite tailored to the project I am making as well, this is kind of unique.

Here is my code so far and here's what I have tried so far.

**This is the Reservations / Index.html.erb file**

```
<div class="house">

    <%= image_tag("restaurant-floor.jpg", class: "floor") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "top-right-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("toprightbooth.png", class: "top-right-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "top-left-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("northleft.png", class: "top-left-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "diagonal-upper-left-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("upperleftbooth.png", class: "diagonal-upper-left-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "left-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("leftbooth.png", class: "left-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "diagonal-bottom-left-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("bottomleftbooth.png", class: "diagonal-bottom-left-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "bottom-left-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("bottomleft.png", class: "bottom-left-booth") %>


    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "bottom-right-booth-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("bottomrightbooth.png", class: "bottom-right-booth") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-left-bottom-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-left-bottom") %>


    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-left-top-empty") %>

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-left-top") %>


    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-top-left-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-top-left") %>


    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-top-middle-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-top-middle") %>


    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-top-right-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-top-right") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-bottom-left-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-bottom-left") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-bottom-middle-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-bottom-middle") %>

    <%= content_tag(:div, nil, remote: true, class: "round-table-middle-bottom-right-empty") %> 

    <%= image_tag("roundtable.png", class: "round-table-middle-bottom-right") %>


    <%= render 'reservation_form' %>

</div>
```

**This is the reservations form:**

```
<%= form_for @reservation, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :num_of_people, "Number of Guests"%>
  <%= f.number_field :num_of_people %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :reservation_time, "Reservation Time" %>
  <%= f.time_field :reservation_time %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%= f.label :table_id, "Table ID"%>
<%= f.text_field :table_id, value: "" %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**This is the CSS**

```
.navbar-nav img{
    margin-top: 3%;
    width: 27%;
}

.wrapper{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#signup-popup {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 35%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}

#signin-popup {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 35%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}

#signin-popup p{
    margin-top: 10%;
}

#signin-popup img{
    width: 30%;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#signup-popup p{
    margin-top: 10%;
}

#signup-popup img{
    width: 30%;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#flash{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}


.navbar-default{
    padding-right: 15%;
    padding-left: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}


.banner{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 66%;
    height: 65vh;
}

.floor{
    margin-top: 124px;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.top-right-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 229px;
    left: 614px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.top-right-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 229px;
    left: 614px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}


.top-left-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 238px;
    left: 452px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   

}

.top-left-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 238px;
    left: 452px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

}

.diagonal-upper-left-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    left: 338px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.diagonal-upper-left-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    left: 338px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

}

.left-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 401px;
    left: 307px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.left-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 401px;
    left: 307px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

}

.diagonal-bottom-left-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 522px;
    left: 338px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.diagonal-bottom-left-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 528px;
    left: 338px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.bottom-left-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 566px;
    left: 454px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.bottom-left-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 566px;
    left: 454px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.bottom-right-booth{
    position: absolute;
    top: 578px;
    left: 615px;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.bottom-right-booth-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 578px;
    left: 615px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-left-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    top: 465px;
    left: 446px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-left-bottom-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 465px;
    left: 446px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-left-top{
    position: absolute;
    top: 366px;
    left: 446px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-left-top-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 366px;
    left: 446px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-middle-top-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-top-left-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-middle-top-middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 805px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-top-middle-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 805px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-top-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 920px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-top-right-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 920px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-left{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-left-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 700px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 807px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-middle-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 807px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 920px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;   
}

.round-table-middle-bottom-right-empty{
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 920px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

#new_reservation{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#myform {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.qty {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
input.qtyplus { width:25px; height:25px;}
input.qtyminus { width:25px; height:25px;}
```

**This is the JS File:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flash").fadeOut(1800);
    $(".signup").on("click",function() {
        $("#signup-popup").show();
    });
    $(".signin").on("click",function() {
        $("#signin-popup").show();
    });

    $(".top-right-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".top-right-booth").show();
        $(".top-right-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".top-right-booth").hide();
        });
    });


    $(".top-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".top-left-booth").show();
        $(".top-left-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".top-left-booth").hide();
        });
    });

    $(".diagonal-upper-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".diagonal-upper-left-booth").show();
        $(".diagonal-upper-left-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".diagonal-upper-left-booth").hide();
        });
    });     

    $(".left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".left-booth").show();
        $(".left-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".left-booth").hide();
        });
    });

    $(".diagonal-bottom-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".diagonal-bottom-left-booth").show();
        $(".diagonal-bottom-left-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".diagonal-bottom-left-booth").hide();
        });
    });

    $(".bottom-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".bottom-left-booth").show();
        $(".bottom-left-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".bottom-left-booth").hide();
        });
    });

    $(".bottom-right-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".bottom-right-booth").show();
        $(".bottom-right-booth").on("click",function() {
            $(".bottom-right-booth").hide();
        });
    });

    $(".round-table-left-bottom-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-left-bottom").show();
        $(".round-table-left-bottom").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-left-bottom").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-left-top-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-left-top").show();
        $(".round-table-left-top").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-left-top").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-middle-top-left-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-top-left").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-top-left").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-top-left").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-middle-top-middle-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-top-middle").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-top-middle").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-top-middle").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-middle-top-right-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-top-right").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-top-right").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-top-right").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-left-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-left").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-left").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-bottom-left").hide();
        }); 
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-middle-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-middle").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-middle").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-bottom-middle").hide();
        }); 
    });

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-right-empty").on("click",function() {
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-right").show();
        $(".round-table-middle-bottom-right").on("click",function() {
            $(".round-table-middle-bottom-right").hide();
        });         
    });

    $(".top-right-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A1");   
    });

    $(".top-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A2");   
    });

    $(".diagonal-upper-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A3");   
    });

    $(".left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A4");   
    });

    $(".diagonal-bottom-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A5");   
    });

    $(".bottom-left-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A6");   
    });

    $(".bottom-right-booth-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("A7");   
    });

    $(".round-table-left-bottom-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B1");   
    });

    $(".round-table-left-top-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B2");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-top-left-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B3");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-top-middle-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B4");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-top-right-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B5");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-left-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B6");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-middle-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B7");   
    }); 

    $(".round-table-middle-bottom-right-empty").on("click",function() {
        $("#reservation_table_id").val("B8");   
    });     

});
```

**And this is the Reservations Controller**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end


  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params.merge(email: current_user.email, user_id: current_user.id))
    # @reservation.table 
    @reservation.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reservations_path }
      format.js # render reservations/create.js.erb
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:num_of_people, :reservation_time, :table_id, :email, :user_id)
  end
end
```

**I was trying to follow some tutorials so I created a create.js.erb file in the reservations folder and added this code:**

```
$('').append(@reservations)
```

However, I realized something, I have no idea what to put for the single quotes after the dollar sign. I've seen this done for blog comments and the like, but my project is different. For my project, you have to click on a div element (which could be ANY of those possible 15 tables on that table map), which is then anchored to a value located in the Table ID form field. Does anyone have any idea of how I would go about doing this or even yet, if I do manage to get on the right track, how I would even check to see if AJAX is remotely working?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to update a Owners' browser when the User makes a reservation.

If this is the case, you will have to use AJAX/JS, but that is not all.  You will need a pub sub system as well.

ActionCable is the new Rails 5 way of doing this, but it is brand new and just merged into Rails.  There is also a gem called faye that has been around for quite a while that can do the job.

Here are some links to get you started:

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable

https://github.com/faye/faye

https://github.com/jamesotron/faye-rails

I hope I understand your goal and that you find this helpful.  If not, comment and I will try and improve my answer.

Comment: That's correct Andrew, I've been taking a look on youtube and it seems faye can accomplish what I needed. My app is sorta going to go like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSjpv86vNAM

Except instead of squares, they will be table circles. Regardless, I have a sense of direction now and I'll see if I can figure this gem out, thanks a bunch!